# Button doesnt stay transparent when its clicked in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I have a Jetpack Compose app and I want to make sure the button stays transparent when I click it but instead momentarily I see a gray color of it.

This is my Button

```
                Button(
                onClick = onStartQuiz,
                modifier = Modifier.size(buttonWidth, buttonHeight).align(Alignment.Center).background(Color.Transparent),
                colors = buttonColors(
                    containerColor = Color.Transparent,
                    contentColor = Color.White, // change this to the desired text color if needed
                    disabledContainerColor = Color.Transparent,
                    disabledContentColor = Color.Transparent // change this if you have a disabled state and want a different color
                ),
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp) // This is optional, but can help in ensuring the button remains completely transparent
            ) {
                Text("Start Quiz")
            }
```

I am using material 3 library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can remove the button's ripple effect (i.e. the momentary gray color), as it is internally implemented in the Button composable.

As workaround, you can assign `onClick` action directly to the Text component, using `Modifier.clickable`, where the ripple effect can be disabled:

```
Text(
    text = "Start Quiz",
    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
    color = Color.White,
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(buttonWidth, buttonHeight)
        .align(Alignment.Center)
        .background(Color.Transparent)
        .clickable(
            interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
            indication = null, // disable ripple effect
            onClick = onStartQuiz
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to remove the Ripple effect from elements. Firstly, you should create the `NoRippleInteractionSource` class separately like this:

```
class NoRippleInteractionSource : MutableInteractionSource {

    override val interactions: Flow<Interaction> = emptyFlow()

    override suspend fun emit(interaction: Interaction) {}

    override fun tryEmit(interaction: Interaction) = true
}
```

and then you can implement this functionality on your codes (Buttons, TextButtons, and so on)

```
Button(
    onClick = onStartQuiz,
    interactionSource = remember { NoRippleInteractionSource() },  // code is here
) {
    Text("Start Quiz")
}
```